# Non-loading Results with insertCell.innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

For some reason when I put use `.innerHTML` to change the text of the cell, the code never stops and stays within the last statement. How do I get the code to run how it's supposed to run and not stop within the last if statement.

```
w3.filterHTML = function(id, sel, filter) {
var a, b, c, i, ii, iii, hit;
var searchItem = document.getElementById('search-list');
var row = searchItem.insertRow(0);
var rows = searchItem.rows.length;
var cell = row.insertCell(0);
a = w3.getElements(id);
for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  b = w3.getElements(sel);
  for (ii = 0; ii < b.length; ii++) {
  hit = 0;
  if (b[ii].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter.toUpperCase()) > -1) {
    hit = 1;
  }
  c = b[ii].getElementsByTagName("*");
  for (iii = 0; iii < c.length; iii++) {
    if (c[iii].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter.toUpperCase()) > -1) {
      hit = 1;
    }
  }
  //Here is what you need to edit.
  if (hit == 1) {
    // b[ii].style.display = "";
    console.log(filter);
    var row = searchItem.insertRow(0);
    var cell = row.insertCell(0);
    document.getElementById("search-list").insertRow(0).insertCell(0).innerHTML = '<a class="list-group-item" href="#">Hello</a>';
  } else {
    // searchItem.b[ii].style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

}
};
`

I copied the code from [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.js) (the filterHTML function).

Comment: Your question is not clear. What is the meaning of "that if statement"? There are multiple if statements in here

Comment: @ShanilFernandon I edited my question.

Comment: inside the last if statement you are redefining same variable name `row` and `cell`. Please check that three lines after `console.log(filter);`. that three lines are so confusing since you are adding a row,cells and again to same element using its id you are adding rows and cells.